# No me puedo conectar a la base de Datos MySQL con Slim

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, slim

Estoy haciendo una prueba y quiero conectarme a la base de datos `Tarea2` y mostrar la tabla `EMPLEADO` pero no puedo conectarme.

Mi usuario es `root`, por simplicidad de la tarea no tengo passwords

Este es mi código.

```
$app->get('/EMPLEADO', function(){
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Tarea2','root','');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLEADO";
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $EMPLEADO = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  echo json_encode($EMPLEADO);
});
```

pero me muestra un error:

> ---
>
> Slim Application Error The application could not run because of the following error:
>
> Details
>
> Type: PDOException Code: 1045 Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) File:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tarea3/index.php Line: 52
>
> ---

Este es mi línea 52

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Tarea2','root','');
```

¿En qué estoy fallando? Muchas gracias.

Comment: estas seguro que root no tiene password ?

Comment: Si, no le asigne ningún password a la base de datos, es una tarea y por simplicidad no le asignamos, nuestro proyecto final si llevara todos los parámetros de ley, esta solo es una prueba, pero pues no me corre...

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que ese usuario existe y puedes conectarte de otra manera. En mysql no sólo declaras un usuario y password sino que estableces desde dónde puede conectarse.

Si en tu tabla de usuarios tienes a `root` asociado explícitamente a `127.0.0.1`, no es lo mismo que `localhost`, dado que en PDO esto último se interpreta como la conexión a un socket y no una conexión TCP/IP

Si por ejemplo puedes entrar via PHPMyAdmin, verifica a qué hosts está asociado `root`. Puedes añadir entradas adicionales o poner que simplemente esté autorizado desde `%`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O más simple todavía, usar la IP y no pasar el tercer parámetro:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=Tarea2','root');
```

**Edit:** para permitir que root pueda loguearse desde cualquier parte, puedes editar el usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basta cambiar el nombre de host a "cualquier servidor". No tocas nada más y guardas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, elimine el tercer parámetro pero me da otro error...  Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: PDOException
Code: 2002
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tarea3/index.php
Line: 52

Comment: https://ibb.co/cJK2O9 aqui tengo los estatus de root, como le agrego el ' % ' ???